# "Once upon a time" vs. "a long time ago"

Tags: meaning, phrases

How is the meaning of "once upon a time" different from "a long time ago"?

Literally, is that what it means? There seems to be repetition in *once* and *upon a time*. How is this sentence broken up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OED, **once upon a time** means at some time in the past (used as a conventional opening of a story). or **formerly**.

On the other hand, **a long time ago** means a long time ago in the past. Now, they could be used  interchangeably in some cases, but *once upon time* could refer to something that happened a few days or a month ago, which is not long time ago, while the other couldn't.

Comment: Can you explain how the words fit in to the meaning?

Comment: There’s some redundancy in the phrase. *Once* can mean ‘on some past occasion’, *upon* is a now obsolete word meaning ‘in, at, or during (any period of time)’ and *a time* is ‘the period during which an action, condition, or state continues’. It has its origins in Middle English where it occurred in different forms.

Comment: @JNF: *Once upon a time she would have been jealous, but no longer*. *A long time ago(maybe when I was a child), I visited my uncle who lives in the States.*

Comment: @Noah, I meant as in the second part of my question, like Barrie's comment (which is helpful, but if another opinion/insight is available I'll gladly have it)

Comment: @JNF: Barrie has it right. I just wanted to throw some examples, incase someone needs them.

Answer (score 1):

*Once upon a time there was a little girl who loved discussing things over an Internet forum.*

It wasn't a long time ago. A long time ago there were no Internet forums.

Answer (score -1):

*Once upon a time* simply means "not too far from then"
while *long ago* or *a long ago* means "being a longest time"